# Why mail() not sending email?

Tags: php

Why the below code not sending mail to me? What is the error?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $msg="Name: ".$_POST['name']."\n Email: ".$_POST['email']."\n Address: ".$_POST['city']."\n Phone: ".$_POST['phone'];
    mail('sganake@gmail.com', 'New Trial Request', $msg);
    echo '<h2 align="center" style="color:green">Thank you for your message.</h2>';

} ?>
```

No error I got. Just I have not received my email at inbox. This is running on IIS Server.

Comment: Check your spam folder. Check PHP configuration.

Comment: check the value of `var_dump(mail(...))`;

Comment: Check the return value of mail. if it's false, then something blew up within php. If it's not, then check your mail server's logs. PHP's job is to hand the email over to the mail server and nothing more. Everything is up to your SMTP system.

Comment: No error I got. Just I have not received my email at inbox. what to look in PHP configuration ..?

Comment: Read what documentation says http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php *The Windows implementation of mail() differs in many ways from the Unix implementation. First, it doesn't use a local binary for composing messages but only operates on direct sockets which means a MTA is needed listening on a network socket (which can either on the localhost or a remote machine).*

Comment: When I did var_dump(mail(...)), I found ** bool(false)**

Comment: @diEcho When I did var_dump(mail(...)), I found **bool(false)**

Comment: @IndianGirl I recommend you to use Golden Rule which says "google before you ask" Just google *php mail doesn't work on iis* and you'll get a bunch of links with solutions

Comment: @IndianGirl Then there is error with your code. aren't you trying this on localhost?

Comment: @diEcho No, I am not trying on localhost. I am trying on my webhost server

Comment: @IndianGirl you used sometime `"` and sometimes `'`, please maintain consistency in the code. either change everything in `'` or in `"` and then try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$headers = 'From: from@address.com' . "\r\n";
$validate = mail('sganake@gmail.com', 'New Trial Request', $msg, $headers);

if($validate)
{
  echo '<h2 align="center" style="color:green">Thank you for your message.</h2>';
}
else
{
  echo '<h2 align="center" style="color:red">Something went wrong.</h2>';
}
```

If you get `'Something went wrong'` it means problem is in your mail server and not in PHP code.

Comment: At least have the courtesy to mention the reason for the downvote. It's the least you could do

Answer (score 0):

May be your php configuration is not complete, see in `C://xampp/php/php.ini` in:

```
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

This is for activate email. May be your setting is:

```
;sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

Comment: sorry i use xampp, but in every PHP configuration i remove semicolon in sendmail_path and works successfully

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [PEAR::Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/docs) package. You can send emails via SMTP then.

```
require_once "Mail.php";

$from = "your@gmail.com";
$to = "sganake@gmail.com";
$subject = "New Trial Request";
$body = "Name $name, Address $address ...";
$host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$port = 465;
$username = "your@gmail.com";
$password = "password";

$headers = array(
    'From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject
);
$smtp = Mail::factory(
    'smtp',
    array(
        'host' => $host,
        'port' => $port,
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password
    )
);

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
} else {
    echo("<p>Message has been sent!</p>");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You might have to send Mail Using SMTP Authenticationas which is required by many mail servers.
Check [this link](http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm) for further details.

Answer (score -1):

Although I didnt change anything in your code. please try this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name'])){

    $to = 'sganake@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';

    $msg='Name:'.$_POST{name}. "\r\n".
         'Email: '.$_POST{email}. "\r\n".
        'Address: '.$_POST{city}. "\r\n".
         'Phone: '.$_POST{phone}. "\r\n";

    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    var_dump($sent) // just to debug
    echo '<h2 align="center" style="color:green">Thank you for your message.</h2>';

} ?>
```